# How to use excel functions: If, Mod, and Floor

Tags: excel, if-statement, modulo, floor

Hi I am trying to round numbers where I must use the given functions, if, mod, and floor.
Given a price such as $5.50 or $12.19 or any price, if it ends in .00 to 0.49, it should round to .49 and if its greater than .49, it should round to 0.95. I do not know how to approach this. Thank you

Comment: Do they need to be used together or seperatly?

Answer (score 4):

They are pretty straightforward, and if you click that `Fx` button next to the textbar up top and select the function from the list it kind of walks you through.

```
=IF(B1 > 10,1,0)    IF(COND, TRUE_VAL, FALSE_VAL)
=FLOOR(4.3, 1)      FLOOR(VAL, SIGNIFICANCE ie 1 for integers) 
=MOD(11,3)          MOD(VAL, DIVISOR)
```

Your thing, with some examples

```
=IF(MOD(B1, 1) <= 0.49, FLOOR(B1, 1)+0.49, FLOOR(B1, 1)+0.95)

0 -> .49
1.8 -> 1.95
3.1 -> 3.49
```